# compression algorithm implementation and working with bits

Tags: algorithm, compression, bit

I have a project for implementation a new algorithm of compression
I don't know which language or library help me.
in my project I must access to bits of a file or String and process on them.
plz help me
thanks :)

Comment: Use the programming language you know best.

Comment: @Ronald I know java and python
but which one ?

Comment: Doesn't really matter. Both languages allow to retrieve bits from character arrays. I'd probably start with python because the testing is easier. First make it work correctly. If you encounter performance issues with the correctly working program you can always decide to port it to C or any other compiled language.

Comment: @Ronald thank you so much (; 
do you know some site that have some simple or example code ?

Comment: how about https://www.learnpython.org/ ? I didn't read or test it, I just googled for "python tutorial" and the first page looked good